# error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'TessBaseAPI' with no type?

Tags: iphone, ocr, tesseract

I have a OCR application. I'm using the tesseract api library for my app. But when i run the application, it will show the error (error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'TessBaseAPI' with no type?).

Here is myt.

```
@interface OCRViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>{
   UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController;
   //Getting error in this line.
   TessBaseAPI *tess;
   UIImageView *iv;
   UILabel *label;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to add the tesseract namespace, either with:

```
using namespace tesseract;
```

or:

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *tess;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried out following solution this really works
Please rename

**main.m ==> main.mm**

**ViewController.m ==> ViewController.mm**

**AppDelegate.m ==> AppDelegate.mm**

This means that straight C++ style header files will no longer be included (by reference) in your plain Obj-C source.
Hope that helps, and makes sense. If this helps then please give me thumbs up.
Thanks,